# Lazy module not found in Angular version 11

Tags: javascript, angular

This [app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11-slice-ngrx-demo) is trying to load the `BookModule` lazily with this configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/books", pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "books",
    loadChildren: "./modules/book/book.module#BookModule",
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent }
];
```

And it's producing the error:

> Error: Cannot find 'BookModule' in './modules/book/book.module'

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your Angular version is 11.

The lazy loading syntax changed. It is something like this now

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'items',
    loadChildren: () => import('./items/items.module').then(m => m.ItemsModule)
  }
];
```

So your code should be like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/books", pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "books",
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/book/book.module').then(m => m.BookModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent }
];
```